# Solve $a^x = 1-x$

Tags: lambert-w, transcendental-equations

This has the obvious solution $x=0$ but it also has a positive solution (which must be $x<1$, ignoring complex numbers) when $a>0$ and $<\frac{1}{e}$.

I can solve it by fixed-point iteration

Eg:

$a=0.1$  and $x=0.8628711425761376$

or $a=0.3$  and $x=0.31852395682012924$

but does it an analytical solution?

Substituting $\frac{x}{\log(a)}$ for $x$ we get:
$e^x = 1-x/b$ where $b=\log{a}$

So $x = \log (\frac{1-x}{b})$ is an equivalent form, if it helps.

Comment: The answer method is the same as to [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356064/solution-of-ax-ax). So use Lambert's W-function.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot rearrange my equation into Lambert form, so I do not think it is a duplicate.

Comment: As you see, you can. Just substitute $t=1-x$.

Comment: Yes, I concur. Difficult to think in this inverse way. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

(Edited in response to comments.)

\begin{align}
a^x &= 1 - x \\
a^{1-t} &= t \tag{Subtitute $t = 1 - x$} \\
t a^t & = a \\
t\ln a \cdot e^{t \ln a} &= a \ln a \\
t \ln a &= W(a \ln a) \\
t &= \frac{W(a \ln a)}{\ln a} \\
  &= \frac{W(u e^u)}{u} \tag{Subtitute $u = \ln a$}
\end{align}

where $W$ is [Lambert-$W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

The last substitution is for applying the identities for certain range of $u$.

\begin{array}{c|c}
u & W \\ \hline
u \ge 0 & W(ue^u) = u \\ \hline
u \ge -1 & W_{0}(ue^u) = u \\ \hline
u \le -1 & W_{-1}(ue^u) = u
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
a & 0 < a < e^{-1} & a = e^{-1} & e^{-1} < a < 1 & a > 1 \\ \hline
u = \ln a & u < -1 & u = 0 & -1 < u < 0 & u > 0 \\ \hline
a \ln a & \rlap{\bbox[black, 10pt]{\color{white}{\text{between } -e^{-1} \text{ and } 0}}} & & & > 0 \\ \hline
\small \text{Trivial solution } t = 1 & \dfrac{W_{-1}(u e^u)}{u} & {W_{-1} \text{ and } W_0 \\ \text{coïncide}} & \dfrac{W_0(u e^u)}{u} & \dfrac{W(u e^u)}{u} \\ \hline
\small \text{Nontrivial solution } t & \dfrac{W_0(u e^u)}{u} & \text{doesn't exist} & \dfrac{W_{-1}(u e^u)}{u} & \text{doesn't exist} \\ \hline
\small \text{Nontrivial solution } x = 1-t & 1 - \dfrac{W_0(u e^u)}{u} & \text{doesn't exist} & 1 - \dfrac{W_{-1}(u e^u)}{u} & \text{doesn't exist}
\end{array}

---

#### Numerical tests using Python

Here's some numerical solutions for $ta^t = a$ when $a = 0.1, \dots, 0.9$.

```
from scipy.special import lambertw
from numpy import *
avec = arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.1)
t0 = lambertw(avec*log(avec))/log(avec)  # upper branch
print t0
[ 0.13712886-0.j  0.35298438-0.j  0.68147604-0.j  1.00000000-0.j
  1.00000000-0.j  1.00000000-0.j  1.00000000-0.j  1.00000000-0.j
  1.00000000-0.j]
t0*avec**t0
array([ 0.1+0.j,  0.2+0.j,  0.3+0.j,  0.4+0.j,  0.5+0.j,  0.6+0.j,
    0.7+0.j,  0.8+0.j,  0.9+0.j])
t1 = lambertw(avec*log(avec), -1)/log(avec)  # lower branch
print t1
[  1.00000000-0.j   1.00000000-0.j   1.00000000-0.j   1.18811482-0.j
   2.00000000-0.j   3.38979929-0.j   6.04398759-0.j  12.21577702-0.j
  34.64890685-0.j]
t1*avec**t1
array([ 0.1+0.j,  0.2+0.j,  0.3+0.j,  0.4+0.j,  0.5+0.j,  0.6+0.j,
        0.7+0.j,  0.8+0.j,  0.9+0.j])
```

P.S. The above code can be run online thanks to [Python Anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/).

Comment: Worth noting, when $0<a<1/e$, $-e^{-1}<a\ln a<0$, where $W$ is a multivalued function. When $a>1$ then $x=0$ is the only solution, and it means $t=1$, or that $W(a\ln a)=\ln a$, which is obviously true.

Comment: That's great. I couldn't see how to rearrange to Lambert form but it turns out is simple when you can get your head around it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment about the x=0 solution and how this fits the Lambert formula but did you mean  x=0 is the only solution when a>1/e and not a>1.

Comment: @IanHeath When $a = 0.5$, $t = 1$ and $t = 2$ solves the problem, so we need $a\ge1$ to guarantee the uniqueness of solution.

Comment: Regarding the 2 values for a=0.5:  one of them is x=0, which is true for all a, the other value is the one I want.

Comment: @IanHeath Thanks for your comment.  I've added more explanation to all possible cases of positive $a$.  I hope this edit answers your question.

Comment: Many thanks.  That nails it.  You sure do like to investigate all possibilities.  I wish I could confirm you solved this but I can't as I don't have the score to allow me as I am new to this board.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @IanHeath I've added the block of code allowing to verify numerically the solutions for $t$ found in the table.