# Solve $x$ in $x = A^{x}$ for given $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

I can see from graphing the problem that the equation $x = A^x$ will only have solutions when $A < 1.446...$ (approx).

For some value of $A$, say $k$, it will have exactly one solution, and then for $A < k$ it will have $2$ solutions.

How can we work out $k$? And how can we solve for the two values of $x$ given a specific $A < k$?

Comment: Look at *Lambert function*

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356064/solution-of-ax-ax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any special function, consider that you look for ther zero of
$$f(x)=A^x-x$$
It is simpler to take logarithms (assuming $x>0$) and consider
$$g(x)=x \log(A)-\log(x)$$
$$g'(x)=\log(A)-\frac 1 x \qquad \text{and} \qquad g''(x)=\frac 1 {x ^2} ~>0~\forall x$$

The minimum of the function occurs at
$$x_*=\frac 1{\log(A)}\implies g(x_*)=\log (\log (A))+1$$ In order to have two roots you need that
$$\log (\log (A))+1 <1 \implies  A < e^{\frac{1}{e}}=1.44467$$

Now, if $A< e^{\frac{1}{e}}$, the only explicit solutions are given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) which is not elementary but simple. This function has a lot of applications (to give you an idea, just type *Lambert* of the search bar : $3932$ entries).

In the real domain the small and large solutions are
$$x_1=-\frac{W_0(-\log (A))}{\log (A)} \qquad \text{and}\qquad x_2=-\frac{W_{-1}(-\log (A))}{\log (A)} $$ In the linked page, you will find a series of approximations for their computation.

Comment: Thank you very much Claude! This was incredibly helpful.